# numbers behind the ajax long polling url /controller/method?_xxxx

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, long-polling

I'm using codeigniter, I am curious about the get query for long polling I made

```
       function check_new_notif(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"/MAIN/AJAX/new_unotif",
                async:true,
                cache:false,
                datatype: "text",
                timeout:20000,

                success: function(dat){
                    show_new_notif(dat);
                    fetch_new_notif();
                    setTimeout(
                        check_new_notif,10000
                    );
                },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textstatus,errorThrown){
                show_new_notif("error");
                setTimeout(
                    check_new_notif,10000
                );
            }
        });
```

what is the number used for?
when my long polling request on server the links in firebug was like this

```
GET /MAIN/Ajax/notification?_=1466062273034
```

and the next call its `/MAIN/Ajax/notification?_=1466062273035` ,incremented by one

Anyone know what this `?_=1466062273035` query means?

Thankies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `cache: false`, it will append timestamp to your URL

Doc: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the
>   browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with
>   HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the
>   GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of
>   requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already
>   been requested by a GET.